# Binding json, that has a list, with an object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, data-binding, jackson

Given I have the following json:

```
{
    "Company": {
        "name": "cookieltd",
        "type": "food",
        "franchise_location": [
            {
                "location_type": "town",
                "address_1": "5street"
            },
            {
                "location_type": "village",
                "address_1": "2road"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can it be binded to the following object classes using Jackson?:

1) Company class

```
public class Company
{
    String name, type;
    List<Location> franchise_location = new ArrayList<Location>();

    [getters and setters]
}
```

2) Location class

```
public class Location
{
    String location_type, address_1;

    [getters and setters]

}
```

I have done:

```
String content = [json above];
ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(Company.class).withRootName("Company"); //read after the root name
Company company = reader.readValue(content);
```

but I am getting:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "franchise_location"
```

Comment: This actually works. I misread the actual json data feed coming in. `franchise_location` is within another node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you are simply missing an appropriately named getter for the field `franchise_location`. It should be

```
public List<Location> getFranchise_location() {
    return franchise_location;
}
```

(and the setter)

```
public void setFranchise_location(List<Location> franchise_location) {
    this.franchise_location = franchise_location;
}
```

Alternatively, you can annotate your current getter or field with

```
@JsonProperty("franchise_location")
private List<Location> franchiseLocation = ...;
```

which helps to map JSON element names that don't really work with Java field name conventions.

---

The following works for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String json = "{ \"Company\": { \"name\": \"cookieltd\", \"type\": \"food\", \"franchise_location\": [ { \"location_type\": \"town\", \"address_1\": \"5street\" }, { \"location_type\": \"village\", \"address_1\": \"2road\" } ] } }";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader(Company.class).withRootName(
            "Company"); // read after the root name
    Company company = reader.readValue(json);
    System.out.println(company.getFranchise_location().get(0).getAddress_1());
}

public static class Company {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private List<Location> franchise_location = new ArrayList<Location>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public List<Location> getFranchise_location() {
        return franchise_location;
    }
    public void setFranchise_location(List<Location> franchise_location) {
        this.franchise_location = franchise_location;
    }
}

public static class Location {
    private String location_type;
    private String address_1;
    public String getLocation_type() {
        return location_type;
    }
    public void setLocation_type(String location_type) {
        this.location_type = location_type;
    }
    public String getAddress_1() {
        return address_1;
    }
    public void setAddress_1(String address_1) {
        this.address_1 = address_1;
    }
}
```

and prints

```
5street
```

Comment: Hi. Yes I have getters and setters for the field. I just tried to add the annotation and it doesn't work still...

Comment: @obsessiveCookie I'd have to look at what you've done. I've edit my answer to provide a working example try and compare. The getters have to have appropriate names (java Bean convetion).

Comment: :/ Silly me. Problem lay with me misreading and not looking at the json data feed properly and missed nodes. Using the example above, the Location was within another node. The actual code works. Sorry for wasting your time Mr @Delimanolis

Comment: @obsessiveCookie No worries, as long as the problem is now resolved.

Answer (score -2):

my solution for JSON is always [`GSON`](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), you can do some research on that, as long as you have the correct structure of class according to the JSON, it can automatically transfer from JSON to object:
`Company company = gson.fromJson(json, Company.class);`
GSON is so smart to do the convertion thing!
enjoy GSON !

Comment: Thank @Rugal, Jackson could do it too :) I was just being silly and misread the json data feed. Using the example above, the `franchise_location` is within another node.